# How to check many fields as part of one IF statement

Tags: php

I want to make my code as short as possible.

```
 if ($request->ck1 > 5 || $request->ck2 > 5 || $request->ck3 > 5 || ... ) {

 }
```

I have 12 of these fields on the `$request` object, and the condition for all of them is to be `> 5`. Is there a cleaner way to check all of them?

Comment: Maybe you can make a loop but I don't think there is a point to improve this

Comment: Where is `$request` coming from, are you in control of where and how that data structure is created? “Numbered” property names are about as bad as numbered variable names, ideally this should be an _array_ to begin with.

Comment: you can use variable variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the properties are being compared to the same value (5), you can use a loop if you want to:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    if ($request->{'ck' . $i} > 5) {

        // Do your thing here

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont you think a foreach loop would be more efficent, since there might be an ck2 missing. In a foreach, grabbing key AS $key => $val, would be less conditional.

Comment: @ThomasJ. Based on what OP has said, there's no reason to assume a property might be missing, but then I wouldn't have built this as OP has done in the first place. I'm just providing a solution for their current implementation - I'm not going to rewrite their app for them.

Comment: No, dont get me wrong, Im not picking, was just wondering. This coulve been solved few ways, foreach is safer in this case, was wondering if there was a specific reason you went with for. Maybe OP will read it and get some insights ^^, worth a mention.

Comment: @ThomasJ. The reason you probably wouldn't want to go with a `foreach` is because looping through an object directly in that way is dangerous as you don't know which properties are set on it. This would affect your logic if the loop starts reading public properties that are not intended for this check. As I say, I wouldn't have designed the code in this way anyway, I would ensure all the values being checked are part of a safely organised array/collection of some kind, rather than having loads of properties named `ck1`, `ck2`, `ck3`, etc.

Comment: Yeh, I know, however, there is few ways to transform object into array (If going with this approach, yet reaching the consistent approach). But I do agree, I wouldn't build it like that in the first place. Ether way, I didint say that it didint solve it. I did uvote your commenterino ^^ But yeh, we are on the same page.